# Why does subtracting a rank-$1$ matrix shift the singular vectors?

Tags: matrices, matrix-decomposition, svd

> [To compute SVD of a matrix](https://jeremykun.com/2016/05/16/singular-value-decomposition-part-2-theorem-proof-algorithm/): Say you start with the matrix $A$ and you compute $v_1$. You can use $v_1$ to compute $u_1$ and $\sigma_1(A)$. Then you want to ensure you're ignoring all vectors in the span of $v_1$ for your next greedy optimization, and to do this you can simply subtract the rank $1$ component of $A$ corresponding to $v_1$. I.e., set $A^{\prime}=A-\sigma_1(A) u_1 v_1^T$. Then it's easy to see that $\sigma_1\left(A^{\prime}\right)=\sigma_2(A)$ and basically all the singular vectors shift indices by 1 when going from $A$ to $A^{\prime}$. Then you repeat.

Question 1: I didn't understand how the subtraction the rank $1$ shift the singular vectors and $\sigma_1\left(A^{\prime}\right)=\sigma_2(A)$?

To understand this I search for details and came cross the following statement,

> Given a matrix $A_{m\times n}$, the SVD of $A$ is given by:
> $$
> A = UΣV^T
> $$
> where $U_{m\times m}$ is a orthogonal matrix, $Σ_{m \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix with non-negative entries on the diagonal, and $V_{n\times n}$ is a orthogonal matrix.
> For a specific singular value $σ_i$ and its corresponding left singular vector $u_i$ and right singular vector $v_i$, we have: $Av_i = σ_i u_i$
> This means that $Av_i$ is a linear combination of the columns of $U$ with coefficients given by $σ_i u_i$. In other words, $Av_i$ is a vector in the column space of $U$.
> Now, consider the expression $(Av_i) v_i^T$. This is an $m \times n$ matrix that can be written as:
> $$
> (Av_i) v_i^T = (σ_i u_i) v_i^T
>              = σ_i (u_i v_i^T)
> $$
> **where $u_i v_i^T$ is an $m \times n$ matrix with a rank of $1$. In other words, $u_i v_i^T$ is a matrix that projects any vector onto the direction of $v_i$.**
> So, $(Av_i) v_i^T$ can be seen as a matrix that scales the projection of any vector onto the direction of $v_i$ by $σ_i$. Therefore, the matrix $(Av_i) v_i^T$ is an outer product between the vector $Av_i$ and the vector $v_i^T$, scaled by the singular value $σ_i$.

Question 2: I didn't see why the $u_i v_i^T$ matrix projects **any vector** onto the direction of $v_i$? (which seems very different from dot product of $a^T b$ gives the projection of $a$ in $b$ direction where we consider everything is unit vector)

It will be a great help if anyone help me to figure out this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Note that the SVD can be written as $A = \sum_k \sigma_k u_k v_k^*$, hence if you subtract off $\sigma_1 u_1 v_1^*$...

Comment: It is not shifting, it is removing.

Comment: Aha, I get it. The word choosing can make someone confused :) Can you suggest something on Question 2? Like is it a typo? Isn't is should be $u_i$ projected onto the direction of $v_i$? Or I am mixing wrong interpretation with dot product? And sorry, for late response. Thanks in advance. @copper.hat

Comment: $u_i v_i^T x$ takes the component of $x$ along $v_i$ and results in a vector of the same length along $u_i$. The wording looks suspect to me.